# Vague error from Apache and Phusion Passenger on failed Rails apps - how to address such a non-verbose issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm using Apache 2.4 along with Phusion Passenger 4.0.5 and for some reason I am seeing errors come up from time to time for Rails apps without any real seeming rhyme or reason.  When I look into the Apache error logs, I only see the following very vague error:

```
[ 2013-07-01 10:56:01.0046 26104/7ff716d317c0 apache2/Hooks.cpp:757 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to the helper agent
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
```

Any way to force more verbosity from Apache and Passenger to facilitate troubleshooting here?

Answer (score 4):

This error message is printed when the HelperAgent has crashed. The code in Apache will wait until the Watchdog restarts the HelperAgent, after which the connection is reestablished. If anything goes wrong, this is the message you get. What you should look for are the earlier messages. Are there any messages from earlier that may tell you why the HelperAgent crashed in the first place, or why it failed to restart? If you look at passenger-memory-stats, do you see the PassengerHelperAgent and PassengerWatchdog?

Comment: The problem here is that there are no more errors within the apache log and neither in the production.log for the rails app.  It seems as though there is just not any verbosity to indicate anything further than what I've got above oddly and thus why I posted here.

Comment: What about passenger-memory-stats? Have you tried setting PassengerLogLevel?

Comment: Additionally it appears that this is now popping up occasionally I am being told (although I have not personally seen it myself): http://cl.ly/image/140l0r2X1E1P

Comment: I see 'stdin: not a TTY'. There's probably a line somewhere in your bashrc or bash profile that makes it exit if there's no terminal available. Since Phusion Passenger starts application processes through the shell, you must find that line and disable it.

Comment: Hmm, so even though the application seems to run for hours on end with no problem and then suddenly dies, this could be the case what you are saying?  And Passenger runs under the Apache user (`nobody` in this case) or as I'm using `fcgi` I am guessing that it exec's as the owner of the home folder where it is executing from.  Here are my bash init files: https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/080bbb875c9265ac432a -- however I am using `zsh` as my user's shell, so would `zsh` be used instead by Passenger?

Comment: I'm seeing this too... https://gist.github.com/rubys/5944218 in my case, I originally updated my application to run on passenger 4.0.2, Rails 4.0.0.rc1, Apache/2.2.22, and ruby-2.0.0-p195.  I had no problems.  Then I updated to Rails 4.0.0, passenger 4.0.7, and system ruby 1.9.3p0 and have been seeing problems.  Restarting apache clears it up for several hours, then down it goes again.

Comment: Now trying passenger 4.0.2, Rails 4.0.0, Apache/2.2.22, and ruby-2.0.0-p195.  Will report back in a few days if I don't see any problems, and sooner if I do.

Comment: Worked overnight with passenger 4.0.2, rails 4.0.0 and ruby-2.0.0-p195; has already failed once with passenger 4.0.7, rails 4.0.0 and ruby-2.0.0-p247... starting to look like a regression introduced between passenger 4.0.2 and 4.0.7.

Comment: @ylluminate It should not suddenly die. Regarding your shell: on <= 4.0.5, bash is always used to start the application, regardless of your shell. On >= 4.0.6, zsh is used if your shell is zsh. Do you have any luck with 4.0.7?

Comment: @ylluminate Another possibility is that there is a /tmp cleaner service on your system that removes the /tmp directory. Can you check whether the directory /tmp/passenger.x.x.x exists?

Comment: @SamRuby Can you also check whether the /tmp/passenger.x.x.x directory exists when the problem occurs?

Comment: Actually, there is a regression in 4.0.7 which may be related to this issue. When you gracefully restart the web server, it will cause the /tmp/passenger.x.x.x directory to be deleted, which can also cause the symptoms you're observing. It has already been fixed in git master. Are both of you using the open source version? If so can you check whether git master solves the problem for you? Git master is safe to use in production, it only contains bug fixes (which we are going to push into a new release soon). If you're an Enterprise user, email support@phusion.nl for a hotfix gem.

Comment: @Hongli The /tmp/passenger.x.x.x directory was indeed gone when I next saw the error.  I'm now trying git master, haven't seen the problem in four restarts, and will leave it running.  If I see the problem again I'll report back.

Comment: Version 4.0.8 has been released with the fix. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Hongli thanks!  I am now running with 4.0.8 with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Passenger 4.0.7, Update to 4.0.8 or the lasted version of passenger and run again :

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

then update your apache config file.
[source](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=927)